# Gmail API PHP - Request Entity Too Large Error 413

Tags: php, api, email, google-api, gmail-api

I need help understanding Gmails API and how I can fix my script below. I have gone through every post on Stack and all the documentation on Gmail to try and figure out how to send an email using the api with attachments over 5 Mb.

Here is my script. This works fine if the attachments are less than 5Mb. The instant it goes over, I get the 413 error.

> Request Entity Too Large Error 413

```
    # set up the google client...
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setApplicationName("My App");
    $client->setAuthConfig($array['credentials']);
    
    # create new gmail service...
    $gmail = new \Google_Service_Gmail($client);
    
    # set the content...
    $strRawMessage = "";
    $boundary = uniqid(rand(), true);
    $subjectCharset = $charset = 'utf-8';
    $strMailContent = 'Test Message Body...';
    $strMailContent = quoted_printable_encode( $strMailContent );
    $strSubject = 'Test Message Subject...';
    
    # set up who the message is being sent to...
    $to[] = $this->encodeRecipients('You' . " <you@gmail.com>");
    $strRawMessage .= "To: " . implode(", ", $to) . "\r\n";
    
    # set the subject...
    $strRawMessage .= 'Subject: =?' . $subjectCharset . '?B?' . base64_encode($strSubject) . "?=\r\n";
    $strRawMessage .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $strRawMessage .= 'Content-type: Multipart/Mixed; boundary="' . $boundary . '"' . "\r\n";
    
    # set the body...
    $strRawMessage .= "\r\n--{$boundary}\r\n";
    $strRawMessage .= 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=' . $charset . "\r\n";
    $strRawMessage .= 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable' . "\r\n\r\n";
    $strRawMessage .= $strMailContent . "\r\n";
    
    # loop over the attachments...
    $attachments[] = [
        'url'=>'https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/xyz/bugfiles/Pizigani_1367_Chart_10MB.jpg',
        'name'=>'Pizigani_1367_Chart_10MB.jpg',
        'size'=>'10Mb'
    ];
    foreach($attachments as $attachment){
    
        # get the file info...
        $url = $attachment['url'];
        $ch = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_exec($ch);
        $mimeType = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE);
        $fileSize = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_CONTENT_LENGTH_DOWNLOAD);
        $path = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
        $filename = substr($path, strrpos($path, '/') + 1); # $attachment['name'];
    
        # add it as an attachment to the email...
        $strRawMessage .= "\r\n--{$boundary}\r\n";
        $strRawMessage .= 'Content-Type: '. $mimeType .'; name="'. $filename .'";' . "\r\n";
        $strRawMessage .= 'Content-Description: ' . $filename . ';' . "\r\n";
        $strRawMessage .= 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $attachment['name'] . '-' . $filename . '"; size=' . $fileSize. ';' . "\r\n";
        $strRawMessage .= 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64' . "\r\n\r\n";
        $strRawMessage .= chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($url)), 76, "\n") . "\r\n";
        $strRawMessage .= '--' . $boundary . "\r\n";
    }
    
    try {
    
        # Prepare the message in message/rfc822
        $mime = rtrim(strtr(base64_encode($strRawMessage), '+/', '-_'), '=');
        $msg = new \Google_Service_Gmail_Message();
        $msg->setRaw($mime);
    
        # send the message...
        $message = $gmail->users_messages->send("me", $msg);
    
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($message);
        echo '</pre>';
        die;
    
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($e->getMessage());
        echo '</pre>';
        die;
    }
```

What I do not understand is that in Gmails docs it says to use this url when uploading attachments.

```
 POST https://www.googleapis.com/upload/gmail/v1/users/userId/messages/send?uploadType=multipart
```

Or it says to use this URL to be more reliable...

```
 POST https://www.googleapis.com/upload/gmail/v1/users/userId/messages/send?uploadType=resumable
```

What I dont see is where I would even use that URL at all. No where in the classes (Google_Client, Google_Service_Gmail, Google_Service_Gmail_Message) is that option even available to use.

Answer (score 1):

You have a similar error as found here in the google [documentations](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/uploads#simple)  Try using:
Multipart upload: `uploadType=multipart` or Resumable upload: `uploadType=resumable`

and supposedly this is how should work

```
# send the message...
$message = $gmail->users_messages->send("me", $msg, ['uploadType' => 'multipart']);
```

if needed here the api reference [link](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/send)

Answer (score 0):

Google API is strict for some things. The limit for the method you're using (users/SendMessage) which is the right one, is limited to 35MB as per [documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/send). Actually posting with MIME TYPE multipart, in certain cases (almost all) extends the file size to the double. For example, if you upload a file of 20MB, it can end up to be almost 40MB so Google returns that error because in the end they're getting a file bigger than the file size limit.

Comment: Are you suggesting that I remove the line: $strRawMessage .= 'Content-Type: '. $mimeType .'; name="'. $filename .'";' . "\r\n";

Comment: Nope, everything seems right... the problem is how you (and everyone) needs to post data to Google APIS. We need to use the MIME TYPE multipart, which by the way is made itself, almost doubles file sizes... it's an horrible limit, so you can't upload anything larger than (I think) 13MB